# SQL Server: Filtering index with join foreign table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I do filter a unique index to avoid duplication of documents, but this filter should be contingent upon the value that exists in a foreign table

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20131227-100837] 
ON [dbo].[Documents]([ContactID] ASC, [Type] ASC, [AutoID] ASC)
WHERE ((select top 1 ID from  [dbo].[AutoRequirementDocuments] where [Quantity]='Once' and [ID] = [AutoID])>0)
```

Syntax is not right; is there proper syntax?

Comment: You cannot have things like a `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause of a filtered index - you can only refer to other columns in the same row

Comment: Thank you. Then I will use a Trigger?